# How can classes be made parametric in Perl 6?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku, parametric-polymorphism

Normally in Perl 6, only roles are allowed to be parametric. Here, we'll be attempting to make classes, a [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) (referred to from here on out as a metaobject) that isn't normally allowed to be parametric, parametric.

If you try to make a class parametric the naive way, this happens:

```
bastille% perl6 -e 'class Foo[::T] {}'
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling -e
Unable to parse class definition
at -e:1
------> class Foo⏏[::T] {}
    expecting any of:
        generic role
```

But if you take a look at what metaobject the `CArray` type from `NativeCall` uses, you'll find that it's in fact a class, not a role, yet it's still parametric!

```
bastille% perl6 -MNativeCall -e 'say CArray[int32].HOW.^name'
Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW+{<anon>}+{<anon>}
```

How is this done?

Comment: just a little meta-comment: "knowhow" means something more specific; it's a much simplified implementation of classes that is only used to build the stuff that classes themselves are built out of; i think it's more common to refer to these things as "metaobjects" and "metaclasses" instead

Answer (score 8):

Making classes parametric takes a little bit of metaprogramming to accomplish. A simple parametric container class can be implemented like so:

```
use v6.d;

class Container {
    my role ContainerImpl[::T] {
        has T $.value;

        method new(Container: T $value) {
            self.bless: :$value
        }

        multi method gist(Container:D: --> Str:D) {
            $!value.gist
        }
        multi method Str (Container:D: --> Str:D) {
            $!value.Str
        }
        multi method perl(Container:D: --> Str:D) {
            self.^name ~ '.new(' ~ $!value.perl ~ ')'
        }
    }

    method ^parameterize(Mu:U \this, Mu \T) {
        my $type := this.^mixin: ContainerImpl[T];
        $type.^set_name: this.^name ~ '[' ~ T.^name ~ ']';
        $type
    }
}

say Container[Int].new(1).perl;
# OUTPUT: Container[Int].new(1)
```

So how does this work?

Metaclasses that do the `Perl6::Metamodel::MetaMethodContainer` role, such as `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW`, can have additional metamethods mixed in with the type's knowhow (which describes how a specific kind of type, such as a class or role, behaves). Rakudo's grammar invokes the `parameterize` metamethod on any given type with the parametric type and any parameterized types as arguments when parsing a type's name. Normally, types that are parametric are supposed to implement the parametric archetype, but this doesn't get checked here, **which allows any type to be parameterized as long as it implements a `parameterize` metamethod**.

The `mixin` metamethod is specific to the `Perl6::Metamodel::Mixins` role, which `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW` also does. The method mixes in a role by reblessing the class so it's considered to be the same type as the (parameterized in this case) role passed to it.

Combining the `parameterize` and `mixin` metamethods allows you to implement parametric behaviour in a role, then use it in a class by parameterizing it before mixing it in. This allows the class to behave as if it actually were a parametric type, even though it's still technically not one.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** This answer is a "simplified" version of @Kaiepi++'s. It only covers the core bit of code shown below that's extracted from their answer. It's written so that it should work as a standalone explanation, or as an introduction or complement to their answer.

## Making a class parametric

The titular question is very broad. But the body of the question boils down to *making a class parametric* and that's what this answer (and @Kaiepi's) focuses on.

Classes, as a [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) of type, don't support parametricity out of the box. But P6 is fully [metaprogrammable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). So you can just metaprogram a class to add parametricity. **NB. This is *not* an officially supported technique!<sup>1</sup>**

(You *could* add parametricity at the kind level, such that either all classes, or some new kind of type that you derive from classes, are parametric. But I think that would take considerable effort.<sup>2</sup> In the meantime a half dozen lines of fairly straight-forward metaprogramming is all that's required to make a single class parametric. So that's all we'll do in this answer.)

## The code

```
class foo {
    my role bar[::T] {}

    method ^parameterize(Mu:U \this, Mu \T) {
        my $type := this.^mixin: bar[T];
        $type.^set_name: this.^name ~ '[' ~ T.^name ~ ']';
        $type
    }
}

say foo[Int].new.perl;
# OUTPUT: foo[Int].new
```

The above code is extracted from @Kaiepi's answer, leaving out what I considered non-essential. The rest of this answer explains the code in detail.

## `role bar[::T]`

A `role` collects attributes and methods together just like a class. The key difference in the context of this SO is that a role is parameterizable and can be added to a class so that the class becomes parameterized.

The bit between the `[` and `]` is a signature. The `::T` is [a type variable](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/role#Parameterized_roles). The signature can be as complex as you want it to be, just like a regular function signature.

The `bar` role I've shown has an empty body. In an actual application of this technique you would write the attributes and methods that you want added to the `foo` class. These would be attributes and methods that need to make use of the parameterization, plus other attributes and methods that it's reasonable to include in the same role.

## `^some-method-name`

A `^` at the start of a method name signals that it will *not* be a call on its explicit invocant but rather a call "up to" the invocant's "**h**igher **o**rder **w**orkings" as embodied in a [*knowhow*](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop#HOW) object that *knows how that [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) of type* works.

Declaring a method with an initial `^` causes the *knowhow* object for the containing class to be customized to include that method.

## `^parameterize`

If you write `foo[...]` where the compiler expects a type, the compiler calls (the equivalent of) `foo.^parameterize` which turns into a call to `parameterize` on `foo`'s knowhow object.

And `foo`'s knowhow object has been customized to include our method:

```
method ^parameterize(Mu:U \this, Mu \T) {
    my $type := this.^mixin: bar[T];
    $type.^set_name: this.^name ~ '[' ~ T.^name ~ ']';
    $type
}
```

## `\this`

What's `this` all about? (The `\` just means "slash the sigil"; I don't mean that aspect.)

`this` is the `foo` type object, i.e. the same type object associated with `self` in ordinary methods in `foo` that don't start with `^`.<sup>3</sup>

## Adding `bar` to `foo` so that `foo` gets parameterized

We've now arrived at the point where we can generate a parameterized `foo`:

```
    my $type := this.^mixin: bar[T];
```

Starting with an unparameterized `foo` held in `this` we ["mix" in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) `bar` parameterized with the `T` passed to `^parameterize`.

## Following protocol for P6's nominal type system

This line ensures our new parameterized type plays well with the system:

```
    $type.^set_name: this.^name ~ '[' ~ T.^name ~ ']';
```

## Moving on to @Kaiepi's answer

This answer is a simplified version of @Kaiepi's answer.

It isn't sufficient to cover issues such as ensuring that `.perl` works correctly if an actual implementation is a class with parameterized public attributes.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Many details of the metamodel are not part of [official P6](https://github.com/perl6/roast/). The `.^parameterize` method is not.

<sup>2</sup> I'm pretty confident that, with suitable (learning about guts and) metaprogramming, one could make all classes, or a new kind derived from classes, behave like [*roles*](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-role) inasmuch as being a kind of type that supports parameterization "out of the box" using the obvious syntax:

```
class foo[::T] { ... }
```

<sup>3</sup> I strongly concur with @Kaiepi's decision *not* to use `\self` as the first parameter of a `^` method. That would be a lie and shadow the usual `self`. Presumably @Kaiepi's thinking is that `this` is often used as a synonym of `self` but, if you know P6, clearly *isn't* the same as `self` because it's the first parameter but not the invocant parameter.

Comment: I love your detailed answers @raiph. This permitted me to answer my question on HOW mixin. Actually I do not mix HOW but use your (undocumented) META-method overwrite `method ^parameterize`. Unfortunately this does not work for roles that lack of `Perl6::Metamodel::MetaMethodContainer`.

Comment: Thanks for affirmation that extensive detail works for you and that this answer helped you get something done. :) You've probably already figured this out, but @Kaiepi has pretty much been the leading metaprogramming explorer on SO so far. They taught me most of what I know that isn't in the design and user docs. Also, most of my SO metaprogramming contributions have been just reinterpreting what they say in my own way. And I think Kaiepi likely learned some basic stuff from Brad Gilbert. So those folk, plus of course jnthn, are authors to especially look for regarding metaprogramming stuff.